# Right angle bracket in a bookmarklet in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bookmarklet

I'm trying to include a JavaScript bookmarklet in my Wordpress post. The bookmarklet uses jQuery with a child selector ">" (right angle bracket) and looks something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:$('ul>li') ...">Bookmarklet</a>
```

But when I use the right angle bracket in there, it messes up the page layout and the bookmarklet element doesn't actually appear in the post.

Comment: Why are you using it in href? what is your expected result?

Comment: It's a bookmarklet. Users drag them to their bookmarks, and when a bookmarklet is clicked on in the bookmarks, the associated javascript is executed.

Comment: ok. I just wrote an answer. Take a look, it might help. I it's not a good practice to write javascript within href attr. you can call a function there like `href="javascript:anchorScr()"`. or you can put a id attr within the anchor tag. Then target the id and execute your code on click event.

Comment: It helped in a way :) Got me thinking about modifying the link via JS after creating it in HTML. It has to have the link in href, that's how bookmarklets work. Take a look about bookmarklets here: https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-make-a-bookmarklet-for-your-web-application/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with a tip from Sharif.

The ">" symbol can't be included in the href attribute of an  element in WordPress (at least not in my instance?). But it's possible to add a script right after the element that modifies its href attribute to whatever value we want.

Thus, the structure of the final code is:

```
<a href="whatever" id="uniqueid">Bookmarklet</a>
<script> document.getElementById("uniqueid").href = "javascript:$('ul>li')..."; </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This calls the `anchorScr` function when the anchor is clicked:

```
href="javascript:anchorScr()"
```

The function then attaches a `click` event handler to all a elements.

Remove the href and just have this:

```
jQuery('a').click(function (event) {

 //your code
});
```

The code will execute - attaching the click event handler to all a elements. You should probably only run this on

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('a').click(function (event) {

   //your code
  }); 
});
```

to ensure that the page has fully loaded into the DOM.